# How to make a javascript live preview

Tags: javascript

I have a blog style website . I want to create a live preview button that show me the post before sending it to db.

Until now i tried something but i don't know how to make it work. This is my code kinda poorly adapted. I tried to use:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = this.value">Click me</button>
```

But i don't know how to write instead of this.valuea my textarea class and show me the code with the style applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you write innerHTML = this.value, you reffer to the value attribute of the button.
Rather do innerHTML = document.getElementById("yourSource").value